# React event type in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can't build my React/Typescript app when I use `MouseEvent` type in my event handler:

```
private ButtonClickHandler(event: MouseEvent): void
{
    ...
}
```

I get:

```
error TS2322: Type '{ onClick: (event: MouseEvent) => void; children: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'.
  Type '{ onClick: (event: MouseEvent) => void; children: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>'.
    Types of property 'onClick' are incompatible.
      Type '(event: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventHandler<MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>>'.
        Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
          Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent'.
            Property 'fromElement' is missing in type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>'.`
```

I also tried `MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>` but then I got `error TS2315: Type 'MouseEvent' is not generic.`.

Why?

Excerpt from my `package.json`:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.0.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.5",
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.7",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0"
  }
```

**Edit #1:**

Binding in `render()`:

```
<button onClick={ this.ButtonClickHandler }>Toggle</button>
```

in `constructor`:

```
this.ButtonClickHandler = this.ButtonClickHandler.bind(this);
```

Comment: Could you please show us the code where you binding this handler to element? I think there could be a root cause of this problem

Comment: You mean binding in render and constructor? Added in edit #1

Comment: Did you try `(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>)`?

Comment: Yes, same efect. It seems other people don't have such problems:
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3293-hello-world-with-webpack-and-typescript-2-3-4-in-react-15-6-1.htm

Comment: `private ButtonClickHandler(event: React.MouseEvent<HtmlButtonElement>): void` should work

Comment: it gives: `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HtmlButtonElement` and
`error TS2352: Type 'MouseEvent<any>' cannot be converted to type 'MouseEvent'. Property 'fromElement' is missing in type 'MouseEvent<any>`

Answer (score 49):

I think what's happening here is that there are two distinct types available: `MouseEvent` from jsx/lib/js/js/web.jsx (which has no type parameters), and `React.MouseEvent<T>` from @types/react/index.d.ts (which has one type parameter, `T`, the type of the element from which it came). Typescript uses [structural typing](https://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/09/23/structural-typing-compile-time-duck-typing/), so even though they are distinct types, they *can* be compatible. But in order to be compatible with the `onClick` handler you need to use React's version, with an appropriate type for `T` (`HTMLElement` will work, or you can be more specific if you know what element you're attaching this handler to).

So `event: MouseEvent` fails because `onClick` requires the specialized version of the event type. `event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>` fails because it refers to the wrong `MouseEvent` type, the one without a type parameter. `React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>` works because you get the proper type, give it the parameter it needs, and the resulting type is compatible with the `onClick` handler.

Comment: thanks helped me too. it seems a shame such basic issues are failing for typescript out of the box with react. adding an onClick event requires this much google fu to get it to work.

Comment: You may use `React.MouseEvent<Element>` to be more open.

Answer (score 36):

I had the same issue but was able to fix it by explicity importing the `MouseEvent` from `React`

I had the error with this

```
import React from 'react';
```

But fixed with this

```
import React, { MouseEvent } from 'react';
```

Answer (score 5):

You won't belive it: It was enough to move constructor assigment to render function:

```
render()
{
return (
<button onClick={ this.Button_Click.bind(this) }>Toggle</button>
)}
```

Then `MouseEvent` become avaliable:

```
private Button_Click(event: MouseEvent): void
```

Why this is happening?